# Set default custom post type for XML-RPC

Tags: custom-post-types, xml-rpc

So now that [it is possible](http://www.maxcutler.com/2012/04/04/xml-rpc-in-wordpress-3-4/) to work with Custom Post Types over XML-RPC, has anyone figured out a way to set the post type for all items coming in via XLM-RPC to a default post type?

IFTTT has a [WordPress action](http://ifttt.com/channels/wordpress/actions/32) that lets you create a photo post via XML-RPC.

Both are coming through as default posts, and I would like to make it possible to set all posts coming in over XML-RPC to a custom-post type.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There was a question on [WASE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) regarding this exact thing: [How to post to WP custom post type from IFTTT.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26528/how-to-post-to-wordpress-custom-post-type-from-ifttt-com). One of the [answers had a nice hack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26531/11279), but it would only work with a single post type and cannot be changed - all incoming XML-RPC would be changed to that particular post type :(

Maybe there's a way to determine the incoming URL from IFTTT (ie, facebook, youtube, etc) and then create an 'if then' statement in `functions.php` to select the correlating post type of your choosing for that type of IFTTT/URL? Just speculating.

### Edit

Just had a thought: you can specify what category your post from IFTTT will be - what if you created a custom loop/styling based on the category chosen?

```
if ( $cat_from_ifttt = $category ) {
    //choose custom loop/styling?
}
```

It's not exactly custom_post_types, but it's a possible workaround?